# jdoc/pydoc/rdoc for bash?

Tags: bash, documentation

Is there a jdoc/pydoc/rdoc style inline documentation system for bash?

I have a library of bash functions that could really use some nice inline docs that I can convert to HTML for easy reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask and ye shall [receive](https://launchpad.net/bashdoc). Also, see the [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=bashdoc) since it looks like there may be more than one that use the name "bashdoc"

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is man pages, and man2html.

Comment: I was looking more for something inline for functions within a bash-script.